# Python: subset from an array based on another array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a training data set and the corresponding labels, which looks like this:

Data X array

```
X =[ [1,0,1,1,1,0 ],
   [1,0,1,0,1,0 ],
   [1,0,0,1,1,1 ],
   [1,0,1,1,1,0 ],
   [0,0,0,1,1,1 ],
   [1,0,0,1,0,1 ],
   [0,1,0,1,1,0 ],
   [1,0,0,1,1,1 ]]
```

Labels Y

```
Y= [ ['YES'],
   ['NO'],
   ['YES'],
   ['YES'],
   ['YES'],
   ['NO'],
   ['YES'],
   ['NO'],]
```

I want to balance the classes for the data, what I want to do to subset the data `X` based on the labels that `Y=YES`. Since the data is already random sampled, so I just want to select the first 3 rows of X given that `Y=YES`, while the rows that `Y= NO` keep the same, so the data X and labels that I subset should look like:

```
Sub_X =  [ [1,0,1,1,1,0 ],
           [1,0,1,0,1,0 ],
           [1,0,0,1,1,1 ],
           [1,0,1,1,1,0 ],

           [1,0,0,1,0,1 ],

           [1,0,0,1,1,1 ]]
```

Labels after subsetting

```
Sub_Y = [ ['YES'],
          ['NO'],
          ['YES'],
          ['YES'],

          ['NO'],

          ['NO'],]
```

My primary idea to write the code is as follows,

```
Sub_X = X[Y=='YES'][:3,]
Sub_Y = Y[Y=='YES'][:3,]
```

My idea is to filter X data based on labels, then select the first 3 rows, but the problem is that the labels = 'NO' should also included as original. Could anyone give me idea to solve this?

Comment: Repeat the same procedure with `"NO"` and concatenate?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. It seems we can do it like `numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0)` . But I also fail to select  the first 3 rows from the class Y = "YES". Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Well I don't see anything wrong with your code, if it doesn't work you need to explain why...

Comment: Do you have pandas?

Comment: Ah! You need `Y` to be 'flat" i.e. of shape `(8,)` rather than shape `(8,1)`. Just remove the inner brackets or use `np.ravel()`, `np.reshape()` or any other reshaping function...